# How to calculate the cumulative sum of each column of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, cumulative-sum, dolphindb

Here is a matrix *m* (111 121 222, 222 234 421):

[image]

I want to get a new matrix of the same size containing the cumulative sums for each column of *m*.

The following is what I expect:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? If so, can you share some best practices? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks `cumsum` is for you:

```
m = matrix(111 121 222, 222 234 421)
cumsum(m)
```